# Recycler view doesn't render inside Fragment

Tags: android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-nested-fragment

I have a fragment where I am trying to display a recyclerview with few data. But nothing seems to be working, the emulator finally shows a blank screen.

The PreferenceMenuFragment is added via xml inside Settings Fragment layout. The full hierarchy of my activity & fragments is as follows.

```
NewDemoActivity(parent activity)
    SettingsFragment(Child of NewDemoActivity) 

                   1. PreferenceMenuFragment
                   2. DetailsFragment
```

**SettingsFragment**

```
public class SettingFragment extends Fragment implements IMqttListener, 
IPropertyChangeListener, ViewVisibilityChangeListener {

private NewDemoActivity mActivity;




@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mActivity = (NewDemoActivity) requireActivity();

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_layout, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    

}
```

}

**settings_layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/black">


<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/pref_fragment_container_view"
    android:name="com.xx.xx.xx.xx.PreferenceMenuFragment"
    android:layout_width="318dp"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="79dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/details_fragment_container_view"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/details_fragment_container_view"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/details_fragment_container_view"
    android:layout_width="540dp"
    android:layout_height="597dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="41dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="76dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/pref_fragment_container_view"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**PreferenceMenuFragment**

```
public class PreferenceMenuFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private NewDemoActivity mActivity;
private List<String> menu_titles;
private int[] menu_icons=new int[]{R.drawable.brightness_icon_blue,R.drawable.bluetooth_icon_blue,R.drawable.camera_icon_blue,R.drawable.seat_alignment_icon_blue,R.drawable.notification_icon_blue,R.drawable.display_theme_icon_blue
        ,R.drawable.language_icon_blue,R.drawable.about_icon_blue};
private int[] selected_menu_icons=new int[]{R.drawable.brightness_icon_white,R.drawable.bluetooth_icon_white,R.drawable.camera_icon_white,R.drawable.seat_alignment_icon_white,R.drawable.notification_icon_white,R.drawable.display_theme_icon_white,
        R.drawable.language_icon_white,R.drawable.about_icon_white};

public PreferenceMenuFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment PreferenceMenuFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static PreferenceMenuFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    PreferenceMenuFragment fragment = new PreferenceMenuFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
    menu_titles = 
Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.setting_option_title));

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_preference, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.setting_menu_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    SettingsMenuAdapter menuAdapter=new SettingsMenuAdapter(getContext(),menu_titles,menu_icons,selected_menu_icons);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(menuAdapter);

}
```

}

**fragment_preference.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/black">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/setting_menu_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="719dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.046"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.369" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**SettingsMenuAdapter**

```
public class SettingsMenuAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SettingsMenuViewHolder> 
{

Context context;
List<String> label;
int[] icons;
int[] selectedMenuIcons;
int selectedPosition;

public SettingsMenuAdapter(Context context, List<String> label, int[] icons, int[] selectedIcons) {
    this.context = context;
    this.label = label;
    this.icons = icons;
    this.selectedMenuIcons = selectedIcons;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public SettingsMenuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new SettingsMenuViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.settings_item_layout,parent,false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SettingsMenuViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.textView.setText(label.get(position));
    if(position==selectedPosition){
        holder.parentItemLayout.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_rounded_corner));
        holder.textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white,context.getTheme()));
        holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(selectedMenuIcons[holder.getBindingAdapterPosition()],context.getTheme()));

    }else{
        holder.parentItemLayout.setBackground(null);
        holder.textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.seekbar_blue,context.getTheme()));
        holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(icons[holder.getBindingAdapterPosition()],context.getTheme()));
    }

    holder.parentItemLayout.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        selectedPosition=holder.getBindingAdapterPosition();
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return label.size();
}
```

}

**settings_item_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/setting_item_parent_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="45dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center"
android:clickable="true">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/settingsItemImage"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/settingsItemLabel"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"/>


</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fragment and adapter looks fine. Check your `fragment_preference.xml` once.
Remove margins and constraints from `RecyclerView` and try once.

Comment: Thanks ! After removing the margins I am able to see the recycler view with appropriate data. The margin was added anonymously by the tool while adding the constraints due to which the recycler view was not showing up.